# How can I append a character to a string?

Tags: c, pointers, char

Is this possible? That is, append a single char to a char*?

```
char temp[10] = "";

while (isalnum(*x)) {
    strcat(temp, *x);
    x++;
}

enqueue(&head,temp);
```

I have a queue which has a char* as a variable. Then I have a char* to be read, and if the char that it's pointing to is alphanumeric, I want it to append to temp. And after that, enqueue it.

Comment: set the character at index=strlen(tmp) to the character to be appended. Don't forget the null terminator and should be probably do a check to see you have space for it as well

Comment: How is `x` defined? What is `enqueue`? What is `head`? It would be helpful if you could update your question with a small complete program. (I suspect that `enqueue` is not really relevant to what you're asking.)

Comment: The single character returned by `*x` isn't null terminated therefore it isn't possible to concatenate it with `tmp`. Do as @Ben suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming temp will allways be large enough:

```
char temp[10] = "";
char *p = temp;

while (isalnum(*x)) {
    *p++ = *x++;
}

*p = '\0';
enqueue(&head,temp);
```

If you're not sure if temp will allways be large enough, add some checks (which shouldn't need
detailed explanation).

Comment: `temp` was 10 bytes in the question; why did you shrink it to 5?

Comment: Minor: `char temp[10] = ""` could be `char temp[10]` as initialization is not used.

Answer (score 4):

Since `x` appears to be a `char *`, you can use `strncat()`.

```
while (isalnum(*x)) {
    if (bytes_left_in_temp > 0) {
        strncat(temp, x, 1);
    }
}
```

More efficiently, you can count how items in `x` can be copied, and then pass the count instead of 1.

```
int k = 0;
while (isalnum(x[k])) {
    if (k >= bytes_left_in_temp) break;
    ++k;
}
strncat(temp, x, k);
```

However, you should make sure you take care not to append past what `temp` can hold, as illustrated above.

Comment: Better yet, count the number of digits `k`, and call `strncat(temp, x, k)` to append all of them at once.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Nice.

Answer (score 0):

If x is char*, then you can use strcat(temp,x)

Comment: `strcat` doesn't work unless there's a `'\0'` terminator.  See @jxh's answer.

Comment: Also, this might copy characters that are not `isalnum()`.